# HTML button style with 3 horizontal dots

Tags: html, css, button

[image: Please check the attached]
I am trying to create a button with 3 horizontal dots as in the attached screenshot with the below css class and unicode Character “…” (U+2026).

But when I apply background it takes more width and height, can any one please suggest.
In the attached screenshot, I need the first image but getting the second image.

```css
.test:after {
  content: '\2026';
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: #D0D0D0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Is the original button formed from discrete html elements or is it mostly just an image?

Comment: Hi @Ouroborus, the furstone is flex mx:button .

Comment: Why are you using a `div` when what you want is a `button`?

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

Placing a `<div>` inside the `button` allows us to fine tune the position of the dots.

```css
button {
  border: 2px solid #9fa2a4;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(#fbfbfb, #d1d1d1); /* gives the "gradient */ color background"
}

.dots {
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif; /* The Arial font appears to have "square" dots */
    font-size: 36px; /* The size of the dots */
    line-height: 0; /* helps vertically position the dots */
    margin-top: -10px; /* helps "raise" the dots higher */
    letter-spacing: -2px; /* "squeezes" the dots closer together */
}
```

```html
<button>
    <div class="dots">...<div>
</button>
```

Comment: Hi @Sergey, yes it's 100% matching, Thanks a lot, marking it as an answer, actually I don't know much on css styles.

Comment: Hi @sergey, I want the same style for anchor tag not for button, If possible please provide.

Comment: You could use the `&hellip;` entity instead, since that's actually a horizontal ellipsis. Might save you the letter-spacing too.

Comment: Yep, I love using www.ampwhat.com to find unicode characters. My goal was to simply steer away from the "dots background image" approach. But yes, many ways to achieve the dots. I like that the letter spacing gives control of how you want the dots spaced.

Comment: Hi @Sergey , when click on the button you provided it shows black lines at the top, please check

Comment: Hi @Sergey, the font-size: 36px becomes appear as black border at the top of the button when clicked on it.

Answer (score 0):

mostly achieved the required style with the code. Now trying to add empty background before and after 3 dots in the result image.

```css
.horizontal-dots {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 19px;
    height: 14px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle, black 1.5px, transparent 2.0px);
    background-size: 6px 16px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 0.2em;
    margin-left: 14px;
}
.horizontal-dots:hover {
   border: solid .2px #0198E1;
   
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-dots">
</div>
```

Comment: try the `padding` CSS property

Comment: You might want to try a different font to get the dots to be more "rectangular". Also why not just use three dots ... rather than a unicode character. With three dots you can also use the `letter-spacing` to spread the dots farther apart

Comment: Further it looks like the original has a slight gradient background. You can achieve this by: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient
`.horizontal-dots { background: linear-gradient(#f9f9f9, #d1d1d1); }`

Comment: Hi @Sergey, when applying padding the background image repeats and added one more dot.

Comment: Hi @Sergey, applying the suggested line background: linear-gradient(#f9f9f9, #d1d1d1); removes all dots from the background. Thank you for the help.

Comment: why are you applying the dots as a background pattern? Why not just type them in as regular periods `...`?
Like this: `<div class="horizontal-dots">...</div>`. You can then use CSS to modify the way the dots look (make them larger font size, more bold (font-weight), and change the `letter-spacing` to achieve your desired result

Comment: I tried the same and got the second image attached on screenshot.

Comment: When we try the hard code pattern ... OR equivalent uni code '\2026'; applying background becomes difficult as the text settle at the bottom, please refer the second image on the attached screenshot.

Comment: Characters generally have fixed heights even if the drawn portion covers less of the height. There's several unicode characters that are middle dots. For example "black small square", 25AA, as in `content:"\25AA\25AA\25AA";`.